# Is it possible to use add_row function within group_modify function multiple time?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

The sample dataset is as below:

```
a = data.frame(a = as.factor(c(1:3)),b = c(1:3), c = c('q','g','k'))
```

I would like to add two row to the dataset according to `a` :

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'q' |
| 1 | 2 | 'd' |
| 1 | 9 | 't' |
| 2 | 2 | 'q' |
| 2 | 2 | 't' |
| 2 | 9 | 'd' |
| 3 | 3 | 'q' |
| 3 | 2 | 't' |
| 3 | 9 | 'd' |

I used the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% group_by(a) %>% 
  group_modify(.,\(.x,...) {add_row(.x, b = 2, c = ifelse(a == '1', 'd', 
                                                      't')) %>%
      add_row(.x, b = 9, c = ifelse(a == '1', 't', 
                                    'd'))})
```

However, the following error popped up:

```
Error:
! Column names `b` and `c` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
  * "b" at locations 1 and 3.
  * "c" at locations 2 and 4.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Should I rewrite the code in recursive form?
I am trying to avoid to use `purrr::map` multiple times.

Thank you!

*I will apply the function to a much large dataset, so running `add_row` multiple times by hand will not be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a vector of values to `b` in `add_row`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  group_modify(~add_row(.x, b = c(2, 9)))

# A tibble: 9 × 2
# Groups:   a [3]
  a         b
  <fct> <dbl>
1 1         1
2 1         2
3 1         9
4 2         2
5 2         2
6 2         9
7 3         3
8 3         2
9 3         9
```

Comment: No. It is just a coincidence. Please see the edited post. Thank you~

Comment: @doraemon Maybe I don't get what's not working, just supply a vector of values to `b`, see my update?

Comment: I would say my real dataset is much more complicated than the given one. I have already updated it. Please check it~

Comment: @doraemon I mean... I already updated to fit your desired output? `c(2, 9)` instead of `2` and `3`.

Comment: I mean the sample dataset. sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: @doraemon Feels like it's better to use `mutate` to assign your `c` column instead of doing it in `add_row`